# Android give Linear Layout tag

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-sqlite

I am trying to get some data from my database, and for every row of data, create a new Linear Layout. The only problem is that I cant figure out how to give each of the created LinearLayouts an id, and use that id so that when the layout is clicked, I know which one it is, such as the forth one, or the first one. When I try this, I get an IndexOutOfBoundException. I'm using set and getTag for this, and I'm using the counter variable for the id:

```
// Fill data
    db.open();
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    Cursor mNotesCursor = db.fetchAllNotes();
    this.startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

    int counter = 0;

    while (mNotesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String titleText = (mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor
                .getColumnIndex("title")));

        String bodyText = mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor
                .getColumnIndex("body"));

        String dateText = mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor
                .getColumnIndex("date"));

        final LinearLayout cardsLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        cardsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        cardsLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.card_container_background));
        cardsLayout.setTag(counter);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layouLinearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout titleLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        titleLayout.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);

        // Title text
        TextView tvTitle = new TextView(this);
        tvTitle.setText(titleText);

        // Text Font Attributes
        tvTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        tvTitle.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        tvTitle.setTextSize(25);

        titleLayout.addView(tvTitle);
        titleLayout.setLayoutParams(layouLinearParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams titleRelativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvTitle
                .getLayoutParams();
        titleRelativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        tvTitle.setLayoutParams(titleRelativeParams);

        // Date text
        TextView tvDate = new TextView(this);
        tvDate.setText(dateText);

        // Text Font Attributes
        tvDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        tvDate.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        tvDate.setTextSize(15);

        titleLayout.addView(tvDate);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateRelativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvDate
                .getLayoutParams();
        dateRelativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        tvDate.setLayoutParams(dateRelativeParams);

        // Body Text
        TextView tvBody = new TextView(this);
        tvBody.setText(bodyText);

        // Text Font Attributes
        tvBody.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        tvTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        tvBody.setTextSize(20);

        tvBody.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);

        cardsLayout.addView(titleLayout);
        cardsLayout.addView(tvBody);
        root.addView(cardsLayout);

        cardsLayout.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(NotesListActivity.this, NoteEdit.class);
                i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (Integer)cardsLayout.getTag());
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
            }
        });

    }
    this.stopManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);
    db.close();

}
```

Comment: Make an adapter that will inflate these views for you based on the assigned backing array, do not create them (the views) manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout/composite/view ids are useful when mapping elements from the xml layouts to Java objects (i.e. using the findViewById) but when you are creating the objects in Java, I'd stick to Java constructs instead of Android layout specific concepts.  One way to do this is to implement OnClickListener and add the data you want to have available when a user clicks.

For example, create this class: (can be an inner class or static class inside your activity)

```
private class CardClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int id;
    CardClickListener(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("XYZ", "My id is: " + id);

        Intent i = new Intent(NotesListActivity.this, NoteEdit.class);
        // i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (Integer)cardsLayout.getTag());
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }
}
```

Then when setting your onClickListener, do it like this:

```
cardsLayout.setOnClickListener(new CardClickListener(counter) );
```

The CardClickListener keeps track of your id in its private member variable id.  You can then use it from within the onClick method.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still receiving this error: 05-28 18:07:01.125: E/AndroidRuntime(15080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.lioncode.notepad/com.lioncode.notepad.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 1):

increase the counter value you set tag to linear layout . index bound of exception due to    fetching coloum index from cursor.